# awk matching fields in 2 separate files using command containing {BEGIN FS = "|"} returns output of blank lines

Tags: awk, array

Two files: data1

```
    Name       |formula           |no. |dose|days|cost  |msg|em|notes
    Fname-Lname|BXXXT+GG          |8262|4   |14  |57.78 |   |  |sq
    Fname-Lname|SJXXT+GG          |8263|4¾  |14  |105.15|   |  |IB
    Fname-Lname|FJDHT+BH,LG,CQC,ZX|8264|5¾  |14  |46.20 |   |  |IB
```

data2

```
10/12/2020|more-data-3456|105.15
10/12/2020|more-data-3456|95.10
11/12/2020|more.data-3456|30.30
14/12/2020|more-data-3456|45.55
```

I am using the code snippet

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = "|" } NR==FNR{a[$6];next} $3 in a {print $0}' data1 data2
```

To match where a value in $6 of file data1 also occurs in $3 of file data2. Where there is a match print out the whole record ($0) containing the match from file data2.
I am expecting:

```
10/12/2020|more-data-3456|105.15
```

But I am only getting an output of a blank line. I removed  the file separators `"|"` using a `" "` as replacement the command code worked exactly as expected however really want to preserve the field separator as `|` if at all possible . I would like to understand why the addition of a BEGIN block has caused this . Has it caused awk to load an empty array in place of taking data from S6 ? My awk level is just above beginner.
Edit: I have also used the -F parameter with the same result, an out put of a blank line . I am using gawk .

Comment: what about if you do `awk 'BEGIN {FS = "|" } NR==FNR{a[$6+0];next} $3+0 in a {print $0}' data1 data2`? post also output of the command `file data[12]`

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the result of printing the files with `cat -vet`? This shows visually any characters which are non-graphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You probably have DOS line endings, see [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it), so remove that if present (I'm removing that and any other trailing spaces with the `sub()` in my script below).
2. If you're getting a blank line output then you have blank lines in each of your input files but I'd bet you aren't REALLY getting a blank line output and instead you're getting the 1 line of output you should get for `105.15` but the `CR` at the end is overwriting back to the start of the line - pipe the output to `| cat -v` to see if that's true.
3. Your input has blanks before and after the `|`s in some places so you should set `FS` to match - `FS=" *[|] *"`
4. You don't need to write `{print $0}` as that's the default behavior

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" *[|] *"} {sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")} NR==FNR{a[$6];next} $3 in a' data1 data2
```

Comment: Your solution worked thanks !!! I removed your ```sub()``` script , it still worked so no DOS endings. 

What I don't understand is why awk needs to be told about anything  between the field separators in this instance and not others. For example ```awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"} 1 ' ~/awk_tests/data1``` produces the entire file printed out with no problems. 

Piping the original command to```cat -v```  produced one blank line . Is this expected ? 

Just trying to get to the bottom of the problem to improve my understanding of awk .

Comment: Your values in `data1` are not just `|`-separated. Consider `|57.78 |` - the value you want is `57.78` but that's not what's between the `|`s, it's `57.78<blank>`. To get **only** `57.78` you need to tell awk to include blanks as part of the separator, hence `FS=" *[|] *"`. Yes, `awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"} 1 '` prints the whole file as you're not accessing any fields and so not using the FS that you're setting. A blank line of output just means you had blank lines in  the input,

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as-is for me, both with GNU awk 5.1.0 and with macOS awk 20200816.

Which version of awk are you using?

Note that you can also set the field separator with the `-F` command-line parameter; if you do that, then the `BEGIN` block is unnecessary.

Comment: I should have put that in the question. I used the -F command line parameter . Same result,  an empty line .

Comment: Which version of awk?

Comment: I am using gawk

Comment: That's still not a version number, but never mind. Is the `data2` file perhaps in DOS/Windows mode? gawk doesn't seem to like that (I get no output if I convert it to CRLF line endings, though it doesn't seem to be affected by such changes in data1)

Comment: GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
File is not in DOS/Windows format . Created in Gvim on Ubuntu 20.04